# Key stay Null when creating a SymmetricAlgorithm key C#

Tags: c#, serialization, encryption

I am using the following method to encrypt and serialize an object

```
public static void EncryptAndSerialize(string filename,User pObject, string pStrKey)
    {
        SymmetricAlgorithm key = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(pStrKey);

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, key.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
                xmlser.Serialize(cs, pObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I use `SymmetricAlgorithm key = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(pStrKey);` my key remains `null`
Can someone tell me how to create this key?

Comment: That depends on your key management. You can simply create a new key and store that, but normally you will reuse the key for your method. Note that your method should be called `SerializeAndEncrypt`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k74a682y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method does not accept the key as input. The input is the name of the algorithm to create. You would use it like `SymmetricAlgorithm.Create("AES")` or simply `new AesCryptoServiceProvider()`.

To set the key, you would assign the `Key` property of the instance of the algorithm. You can either generate a random key using `GenerateKey()`, or derive a key using something like PBKDF2.

Comment: Don't forget to set the key size first :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(String algName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k74a682y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method does not accept a key, it expects an algorithm name. To create an AES algorithm and a new key you may [construct an `Aes` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and call the [`GenerateKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.generatekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after [setting the key size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.keysize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If the key was already created, you may set it using the `Key` property.